# Can't type hint a local with a primitive initializer

Tags: clojure, type-hinting

Could someone explain me this error:

```
user> (let [^int i 3] i)
CompilerException java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't type hint a local with a primitive initializer, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

I don't understand,

- what exactly I cannot type-hint and why?
- why I can use an array type hint in the same situation?

  ```
  user> (let [^ints ii (int-array 1)] ii)
  #<int[] [I@334a123f>
  ```
- how to type-hint local integer variables?

Comment: See http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Some%20optimization%20tips: "(let [foo (int bar)] ...) is the correct way to get a primitive local. Do not use ^Integer etc."

Comment: Probably because the compiler already knows enough to determine the type of `i` here.

Comment: @A.Webb Thanks. It probably resolves my practical problem.  I'll keep the question open for a while. Hopefully, someone can explain the reason for this limitation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This exception is thrown by the compiler from [this](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/653b8465845a78ef7543e0a250078eea2d56b659/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L5967) line. Basically, if you use an expression which is a primitive constant or something that can be evaluated at compile time to be a primitive constant, like: `(+ 1 10)`, the compiler can detect the type of the object itself and doesn't need type hinting.  Check the `getJavaClass` and `hasJavaClass` methods in the same class in which the earlier link points to. These methods check if the expression is primitive then get the class from the expression itself, otherwise use type hinting if provided.

Comment: This is really interesting to hear, but the entire sections of CH 15.1-3 in the Joy of Clojure (second edition, which just came out a couple weeks ago) is rife with examples to the contrary. Of course their examples mess up in my repl too, but I am curious as to why they are recommending that you do this for optimization. Is there some way to optimize by turning off the type checker or is this a messy edit job and they are actually using an older version of Clojure in which such type-hinting was allowed?